# pd.DataFrame.assign(x=series) without deep copy

Tags: pandas

What's the most efficient way to add a column to a DataFrame and yield a new DataFrame, but without copying the whole data? Looking at the implementation of pandas.DataFrame.assign:

```
class DataFrame()
    def assign(self, **kwargs):
        data = self.copy() # deep=True is the default!
        ...
```

I'm working on a production system that uses pandas and I want to minimize memory use (our dataframes run ~500Mb although are mostly backed by memmapped ndarrays). The above looks very slow in memory (AND time).
~10 deep copies as above unnecessarily brings the full data in to RAM and leads to swapping.  Generally, we shouldn't need more than 500Mb + small indexes, but copies like this kills our servers.

Comment: So by "_yield a new DataFrame_" you really mean have a DataFrame sharing memory for every column except the new one with the prior DataFrame?

Comment: Yes -- I just want a dataframe object has has the assigned column, plus references to the original columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def pd_sensible_assign(df, **kwargs):
    def gen():
        for c in df.columns: yield c.name,c
        for k,v in kwargs.iteritems(): yield k,v
    return pd.DataFrame(gen(), index=df.index, copy=False)

x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
b=np.zeros(len(x), dtype=float)
X = pd.DataFrame({"x":x}, copy=False)

print X.shape, X.dtypes
X = pd_sensible_assign(X, b=b)
print X.shape, X.dtypes
```

I don't like it much because it doesn't handle the case of mismatched indexes.